# copy and paste multiple ranges using autofilter in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on macro that will copy the data from report to multiple worksheets. The macro works fine but I am struggling with one little thing. I would like to copy not only B9:J range but also N8:N however when I put `("B9:J" & "N9:N" & Lastrow)` the macro copies everything from column B to N but I would like to skip columns K, L, M. I tried to put `Range("B2", "N2")` and `Range("B2" & "N2")` in `Copy tgt.Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1)` but it doesn't work.

```
Sub report_template()

Const fromFile = "c:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Desktop\Report.xls"
Dim srcBook As Workbook
Set srcBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(fromFile, _
UpdateLinks:=False)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
srcBook.Sheets("Report Page").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "report"
srcBook.Close False

Dim src As Worksheet
Dim tgt As Worksheet
Dim filterRange As Range
Dim filterRange2 As Range
Dim filterRange3 As Range
Dim filterRange4 As Range
Dim copyRange As Range
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim tgt2 As Worksheet
Set src = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("report")
Set tgt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1")
Set tgt2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2")
Set tgt3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("3")
Set tgt4 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("4")

src.AutoFilterMode = False
Lastrow = src.Range("B" & src.rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set filterRange = src.Range("A8:J" & Lastrow)
Set copyRange = src.Range("B9:J" & Lastrow)
filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="EN > 1"
copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy tgt.Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1)
Set filterRange2 = src.Range("A8:J" & Lastrow)
filterRange2.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="EN > 2"
copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy tgt2.Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1)
Set filterRange3 = src.Range("A8:J" & Lastrow)
filterRange3.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="EN > 3"
copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy tgt3.Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1)
Set filterRange4 = src.Range("A8:J" & Lastrow)
filterRange4.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="EN > 4"
copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy tgt4.Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("report").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will construct multiarea range:

```
Range("B9:J" & Lastrow & "," & "N9:N" & Lastrow)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The macro copies correct columns now but data from column N is copied to column K, not to column N (as I wanted). I followed the same method in next line but it didn't work  `Range("B2" & "," & "N2"`.

Comment: if you want to preserve blank area between your selections, you must copy each range separately, do you have any data in your target K,L,M columns? If not, the simplest way would be copying whole range (from B to N) and then clearing from K to M

Comment: columns K,L aqnd M contain formulas that change every month and I don't want to "touch" these columns. I will copy each range seperately then. Thank you for your help.